# How can I ssh to a unix machine and tail from Java?

Tags: java, ssh, tail

I wish to ssh to a remote Unix machine and then `tail -f` reliably. Does anyone know if there is a library or some way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

We used to use http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ back in 2004 — worked just fine for us.

Running processes is a good option as well, but it makes you bound to a particular OS (or a particular set of OS's).

Check out the [sources](http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/SSHExec.java.htm) of `ant`'s `sshexec` task: they use the same library. The connection is kept by a library; the output stream is set up by `setOutputStream` and `setExtOutputStream`.

What you may need is to remove the timeout—or make it a little bit more smart so that you'd only drop connection if there are no new data for quite a while.

Comment: How did you manage to keep the connection open and read from the "tail -f" output?

Comment: Thanks. I checked the sources and I noticed it uses System.out. Do you know if it works with multiple "tail -f"s? I guess I'm trying to figure out if it is thread safe

Comment: there are two options with multiple `tail`s: first, open many connections, and then you're  as thread safe as your code is (and no, you don't need to use `System.out`); second, run `tail -f &` multiple times on the remote side—and enjoy one connection on Java side. The latter is perfectly thread-safe (but you may not like the result).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply start a new process and execute any shell command you wish. Something like:

```
String[] procArgs = { "ssh", "arguments" }; // set arguments here.
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(procArgs);
```

Comment: good suggestion but the machine I am running Java on may not have ssh installed